Dynamic table headers height
The second like works fine but the first one doesn't even exist:
DataTable(
        dataColumnMaxHeight: double.infinity,
        dataRowMaxHeight: double.infinity,

How could I make the headers size responsive? I don't want to have a fixed height.
